# Parsing property in ASP version 4 causes FormatException

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have this code fragment

```
public Version BuildVersion =Version.Parse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BuildVersion"].ToString());
```

which reads following appSetting entry

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="BuildVersion" value="4.7.2.2" />
</appSettings>
```

This throws exception

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument) +10852983
   System.Version.TryParseComponent(String component, String componentName, VersionResult& result, Int32& parsedComponent) +105
   System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result) +135
   System.Version.Parse(String input) +68
   QuickPick.Main..ctor() in D:\IWROX-DEV\Expresslane\IWorx-Trunk-PromoFrontEnd\ExpressLane.Web\Main.Master.cs:52
   ASP.main_master..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e43b3107\2f748eb6\App_Web_main.master.cdcab7d2.uaxqveln.0.cs:0
   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_main_master_cdcab7d2_uaxqveln.Create_ASP_main_master() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e43b3107\2f748eb6\App_Web_main.master.cdcab7d2.uaxqveln.1.cs:0
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance() +30
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +782
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +14
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +335
```

once deployed to the server, However it runs fine on VS2010 web host (ASP NET Development Server).

Comment: How about using a breakpoint and see what actually is returned?

Comment: What is the business reason for pulling this item?

Comment: Are you sure the setting is deployed? Spilt the code into 2 steps.

Comment: @ErikEJ, Thanks, yes, the config file  was not deployed..,and the previous version had a alpha character on it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the correct config file is not deployed to your host.